# Laravel 8.0's Route::post renders a blank page, and same route with get works

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

I'm new-ish to Laravel.
I have this form :

```
<form action="{{ route('foo.store', ['idFoo' => $foo->id]) }}" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

and this route :

```
Route::post('/foo/store/{idFoo}', [App\Http\Controllers\FooController::class, 'fooStore'])->name('foo.store');
```

Also, I added the @csrf, it's not the problem.

So, when this route is used, it renders a blank page , but **if I change both "post" to "get", it works perfectly** (btw the method fooStore is just dd('test')).
With the "post" mode, it won't even look which controller I'm using or anything.
Route post = blank page. No errors, nothing.

**EDIT** : I've found out that the route is not the problem, but the form "post" action is. When the action is "post", it renders a blank page, whatever the route type. But it works perfectly in "get" action.

Comment: you are probably missing the `@csrf` in the form

Comment: No, the @csrf is there.

Comment: I see that you don't have any errors in the page, but do you get anything in the logs? Make sure that in your `.env` file you have `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_DEBUG=true`.

Comment: Which is the output from the `network` tab on your browser dev tools?

Comment: My .env already has the APP_ENV=local & APP_debug=true.

Comment: @kingbeencent nothing weird in the network tab. The request has the inputs of my form and the csrf token.

Comment: @Cosmin There's nothing in the logs, and the .env is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED** : This is the weirdest thing. For an unknown reason, change

```
Route::post('/foo/store/{idFoo}'
```

into

```
Route::post('/foo/store/bar/{idFoo}'
```

solved the problem. I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <form action="{{ url("/foo/store")}}/{{$foo->id}} method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
@csrf 
</form>
```

hope its work

Comment: It didn't. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: I did, but always the same blank page.

Comment: did you have any other routes that would have resolved on /foo/store/*  above your post route?